# Wordpress Sidebar Responsive Width

Tags: css, wordpress, facebook, plugins, responsive

I have created a Wordpress theme with "responsive" sidebar's.  I have set them to 20% width - which works great.  However, I have a Facebook Widget inside my left sidebar which is not "resizing" according to screen width / size.

I have tried the below in my css, with no avail:

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

The facebook widget is still "overlapping" on smaller / narrower screen sizes.

Comment: I suggest building a little practice area instead of just linking to your site next time. The overflow will work, but you will not learn as much with a band-aid. https://jsfiddle.net/xp5knxce/  I'd start with something like this. Also, this doesn't have much to do with WordPress or PHP. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the iframe from overflowing into the middle body content, you could apply an overflow: hidden to the parent div

```
.art-blockcontent {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
}
```

The iframe isn't going to magically squash itself to fit the tiny space on offer ( like the stretched image in the right column) and is probably at minimum viable height / width to actually serve any purpose.

I note that your nav menu is also broken at smaller screen sizes, maybe you would be better off to change the overall breakpoint and have your site go to a one column layout sooner.

Comment: Thank you very much - the iFrame is now resizing perfectly.   Yes I'm working on one issue at a time with this nightmare. 

For the menu, would you please kindly point me in the direction of what you mean by going to a one column layout sooner ?

Comment: Ordinarily I'd say edit your css and change the breakpoints in your media queries, but it looks like your theme is using jQuery to apply a class 'responsive' to the html element. have a look in script.responsive.js and your script.js files to see how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong width in span around the iframe, try this:

```
<span style="vertical-align: bottom;width: 100%;height: 230px;">
```

and

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {
   position: relative;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening when you 'resize' the browser window live or when you are looking at the page at different devices?

Depending on which widget you are using, the official facebook widget I believe has a responsive setting you can select when building it.  I have noticed that the widget itself is only responsive when you reload the page at a different screen size.  Resizing your browser window on the fly will not affect the dimensions of the widget.  It's using javascript to render the widget correctly but only on the page load.